# Is there any way to maintain window scroll position on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scroll, telerik

I am using Telerik version 2014.1.403.40 in my ASP.Net web application, with NET Framework 4.

Is there any way to maintain window scroll position on postback? I tiried setting

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True"
```

but no luck. I also tried various examples to manually scroll the window after postback but still no result.

Comment: Did you try with various browsers? In my own applications, that setting works perfectly in all browsers. You may try with a simple form (e.g. a very tall div followed by a button that causes a postback), and see if you can make it work. That would tell you if the problem is caused by a specific control in your form.

Comment: I tried it in ie Mozilla and chrome. I am using radwindow and i want to maintain scroll inside radwindow

Comment: The `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` flag works only for the main window of the page, not for a particular element (e.g. a div). Maybe the following article can give you some ideas for the RadWindow: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/persist-scroll-position-when-modal-radwindow-is-closed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan as i understand radwindow uses iframe to load content. Does this mean i can not use MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback inside iframe's content page?

Comment: That is right. That parameter maintains the scroll position for the body of the page, not for an iframe inside of the page. Could you avoid the full postback? For example, by using UpdatePanels?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting in code behind in the Page load ?

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack =true;
```

Also, try setting it in the web.config

```
<page smaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"/>
```

If all else fails.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried above approaches  too.

Comment: No worries. I know a while back, this only worked in IE. Have you tried to write a script to maintain it?

Comment: I tried to manually scroll to position from javascript - no luck.

Comment: I've just read an extensive article on MSDN about this. In the top of the aspx page, make sure auto events wire up is set to true and also make sure that the page the gets calledis the correct one. Let me know about this, otherwise I can have a look at a javascript that might be of some help.

Comment: Also, here is a very good example of a javascript that will definitely work for all types of browsers. http://www.redips.net/javascript/maintain-scroll-position/

Comment: I also forgot to mention that i am trying to preserve scroll position inside radwindow, which loads certain .aspx page. I also have set  AutoEventWireup="true"